# Is there any way to make static connection to redshift database in spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I'm using spark API `spark.read.jdbc(String url,String table,java.util.Properties properties)`. It creates a dataframe with the schema that is returned from the database tables.

Every time when I call the above API, it creates a connection request to the DB cluster. Is there any way to pass or create a singleton kind of thing in above API?

Answer (score 1):

Spark is lazy evaluated hence it will trigger only when any action is triggers e.g. `.load()`. I think its not possible for Spark to keep connection to Redshift open until next action is performed. This is feature of Spark where it acquires the connection late and releases as soon it completes the action.

Comment: Do i get any code of load() to better understanding

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala